# Find matrix $A$ if $AB = C$ and $B$ and $C$ are known

Tags: linear-algebra

This is an easy question but I lost it somewhere. I'm reading an article where the author solved the linear system $AB = C$ by $A = (BB^T)^{-1}BC$. Is it correct or not ? According to my understanding, $A = CB^{-1}$.

What if $B: m\times n$ and $m$ is very smaller than $n$ ? Therefore, the author's solution makes sense since he tries to avoid inversion of large matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What really makes sense is to multiply on the right by $B^T$ to get $ABB^T=CB^T$, leading to $A=CB^T(BB^T)^{-1}$.

$A=CB^{-1}$ makes no sense if $B$ is not square. But see the Wikipedia article on [generalized inverses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse).

Answer (score 1):

If $B:m \times n$ then $A:1 \times m$ and $C: 1 \times n$

$A=(BB^T)^{-1}BC$ requires $BC$ which is impossible because $(m\times n)(1 \times n)$ won't work